# Unable to read URL encode in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using express framework in nodeJS and trying to send the activation link on email but as i am activating the link the url get encoded and express routes is unable to read and sending to 404 error page.

```
Url: 

xxx.com/#/user/543fe901b43083207ff0f863c07135b6/xxx.x@gmail.com

On click to URL:

xxx.com/#%2Fuser%2F543fe901b43083207ff0f863c07135b6%2Fxxx.x@gmail.com
```

Can you Please help me out what I am doing wrong or something I have missed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not use the hash sign like this in the url. In fact, the hash sign has a special meaning, everything that follows the hash sign is interpreted in the browser only. It is not used to distinguish URLs, but anchors on the page.

Therefore, express will not parse what comes after the hash sign, at least in its default configuration.